# after downgrading ruby, project still requires last version's file

Tags: ruby

I downgraded ruby from 2.4.0 to 2.3.3 because of incompability with JSON.
Server didn't work, though. I checked my log and found out that it is still trying to execute last version(2.4.0)'s ruby file.

I removed files of ruby last version when I downgraded.
How can I solve this problem?

/.rvm/gems  ls

> cache
>   ruby-2.3.3
>   ruby-2.3.3@global
>   ruby-2.4.0
>   ruby-2.4.0@global

/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0  ls

> gems

/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3  ls

> bin
>    cache
>   environment
>   gems
>    wrappers 
>   build_info 
>   doc
>     extensions 
>     specifications

error.log

> ```
> App 20642 stdout:
> App 20642 stderr: *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/ruby: No such file or
> ```
>
> directory (2)
>       [ 2017-02-20 23:32:45.2704 5334/7fa2e3dde700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:230 ]: Cannot render an error page:
>   Cannot open
>   '/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/resources/templates/error_layout.css'
>   for reading: No such file or directory (errno=2)
>       in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::processAndLogNewSpawnException(Passenger::SpawnException&,
>   const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, const ConfigPtr&)'
>   (Implementation.cpp:206)
>       in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::throwPreloaderSpawnException(const
>   string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind,
>   Passenger::SpawningKit::BackgroundIOCapturerPtr&, const Options&,
>   const DebugDirPtr&)' (SmartSpawner.h:144)
>       in 'std::string Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::negotiatePreloaderStartup(Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::StartupDetails&)'
>   (SmartSpawner.h:617)
>       in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::startPreloader()' (SmartSpawner.h:273)
>       in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Options&)'
>   (SmartSpawner.h:790)
>       in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const
>   SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned
>   int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)
>
> ```
> [ 2017-02-20 23:32:45.2704 5334/7fa2e3dde700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for
> ```
>
> application /home/ec2-user/Karolline.github.io: An error occurred
>   while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling
>   successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
>       Error ID: 34b5bb42
>       Message from application: An error occurred while starting up the preloader. It exited before signalling successful startup back to
>   Phusion Passenger. Please read this
>   article for more information about this problem.
>
> ### Raw process output:
>
> ```
>     * ERROR *: Cannot execute /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/wrappers/ruby: No such file or
> directory (2)
> ```
>
> ```
> [ 2017-02-20 23:32:45.2734 5334/7fa30287a700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-47] Cannot checkout
> ```
>
> session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error
>   is 34b5bb42. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
>       [ 2017-02-20 23:32:45.2734 5334/7fa30287a700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:369 ]: [Client 1-47] Cannot render an
>   error page: Cannot open
>   '/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/passenger-5.1.2/resources/templates/error_layout.css'
>   for reading: No such file or directory (errno=2)
>       in 'void Passenger::Core::Controller::endRequestWithErrorResponse(Passenger::Core::Client**,
>   Passenger::ServerKit::HttpServer::Request**, const Passenger::StaticString&,
>   const Passenger::SpawnException*)' (CheckoutSession.cpp:350)
>       in 'void Passenger::Core::Controller::writeSpawnExceptionErrorResponse(Passenger::Core::Client*,
>   Passenger::ServerKit::HttpServer::Request*, const
>   boost::shared_ptr&)'
>   (CheckoutSession.cpp:282)
>       in 'void Passenger::Core::Controller::reportSessionCheckoutError(Passenger::Core::Client*,
>   Passenger::ServerKit::HttpServer::Request*, const ExceptionPtr&)'
>   (CheckoutSession.cpp:235)
>       in 'void Passenger::Core::Controller::sessionCheckedOutFromEventLoopThread(Passenger::Core::Client*,
>   Passenger::ServerKit::HttpServer::Request*, const AbstractSessionPtr&, const
>   ExceptionPtr&)' (CheckoutSession.cpp:148)
>       in 'void Passenger::Core::Controller::sessionCheckedOutFromAnotherThread(Passenger::Core::Client*,
>   Passenger::ServerKit::HttpServer::Request*,
>   Passenger::ApplicationPool2::AbstractSessionPtr,
>   Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ExceptionPtr)' (CheckoutSession.cpp:114)
>   -- Client 1-47

gem env

> RubyGems Environment:
>     - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.10
>
> - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [x86_64-linux]
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
> - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
> - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby
> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
> - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.gem/specs
> - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/etc
> - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
>   - ruby
>   - x86_64-linux
> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
>   - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global
> - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
>   - :update_sources => true
>   - :verbose => true
>   - :backtrace => false
>   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
>   - https://rubygems.org/
> - SHELL PATH:
>
>   - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
>   - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin
>   - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin
>   - /usr/local/bin
>   - /bin
>   - /usr/bin
>   - /usr/local/sbin
>   - /usr/sbin
>   - /sbin
>   - /opt/aws/bin
>   - /home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin
>   - /home/ec2-user/.local/bin
>   - /home/ec2-user/bin

Comment: What does your .ruby-version file say?

Comment: why not you are using rvm for that `rvm use ruby-version`

Comment: @Shimu .ruby-version is directory, not file.

Comment: If you create a file and just put this line into it it will work too. ```2.3.3```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled ruby 2.4.0 using following codes

```
rvm install 2.4.0
rvm use 2.4.0
```

Then I selected ruby 2.3.3 by

```
rvm use 2.3.3
```